# How to load donut chart data from angular scope object

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, charts

This is my code format:How can I load data from angular scope object.

static data is working fine.But getting from scope object is displays nothing.

```js
var app=angular.module('myApp',[])
 app.controller('myController',function($scope){
 $scope.init = function(){
 
 $scope.loadData()
 var ctx = document.getElementById('mycanvas').getContext('2d');
        var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
                labels: ["EL", "AL", "PL", "CL"],
                datasets: [{
                    backgroundColor: ['green', 'red', 'pink', 'blue'],
                    data: $scope.datas,
                }]
            },
            options: {
                legend: {
                    position: 'right',
                    labels: {
                        boxWidth: 12
                    }
                },
                tooltips: { bodyFontSize: 12 }
            }
        });
 }
 $scope.loadData = function(){
 $scope.datas=[
 {
 'EL':2
 },
 {
 'AL':2
 },
 {
 'PL':2
 },
 {
 'CL':2
 }
 ]
 }
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController" ng-init="init()">
<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

How can I load data from angular scope object for chart.

Comment: from where you got this code? any reference?

Comment: You should try to use angular-chart which can be found here on link, and do it proper way. It contains angularjs directive for Chart.js : http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/#top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost did it right!

The point here is your data format.
You can't pass objects like this.

```
 $scope.requestedLeaveTypeCount=[{'EL': 2}, {'AL': 2}, {'PL': 2}, {'CL': 2}];
```

This kind of data format is working.

```
$scope.requestedLeaveTypeCount=[2,2,2,2]
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/fyXynhYerQSpibVLH0aq)**

Comment: If I sent nothing in `AL` and `PL` also I need to show colors with 0 value.Is it possible?

Comment: @krish not sure to understand. Your dataset becomes: `[2,0,0,2]`. Legends are kept, and donut is drawn right

Comment: If I dont have any value ,my array is empty.on that time also I need to show chart with same colors.

Comment: Ok I see. But if your data array is empty, you can't show any chart

Comment: yea yea that is what i am asking.There is no chances right?

Comment: @krish Honestly I don't know.. When I don't receive data, I usualy 'hide' chart

Comment: Is it possible to grey color when I get no data.

Comment: You can't color an empty area. Assuming that colored zone corresponds to a data value, if there's no data, there's no colored zone